# How to Serve Rails Web App with Apache and Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, ubuntu

I am serving eurohacktrip.org on a digitalocean vps with ubuntu12.04 and apache2.

Here is my apache virtual host file for it: /etc/apache2/sites-available/eurohacktrip.org

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName eurohacktrip.org
    ServerAlias eurohacktrip.org

    DocumentRoot /var/www/eurohacktrip.org/public

    RailsEnv production
    PassengerEnabled on
    PassengerAppRoot /var/www/eurohacktrip.org/
    PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/wrappers/ruby
    ServerAdmin webmaster@eurohacktrip.org

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/eurohacktrip.org/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            # Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

And I added these lines on my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-4.0.40/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-4.0.40
  PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/wrappers/ruby
</IfModule>
```

And I did

```
service apache2 restart
```

But my site still doesnt work : `http://eurohacktrip.org/`
Strange enough It works on 3000 `http://eurohacktrip.org:3000`

I also had to Uncomment

```
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
```

and ran

```
bundle install
```

but still no luck. What could be missing?

Comment: Depending on how far along you are, I'd consider using Digital Ocean's pre-built Nginx/Unicorn server, rather than manually setting up apache/passenger

Comment: It should just work out of the box.

Comment: Looks like passenger is running in standalone mode, in that case port number can be specified with the `--port` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 LoadModule passenger_module /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.40/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerRoot /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.40
     PassengerDefaultRuby /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/wrappers/ruby
   </IfModule>
        <VirtualHost *:80>
              ServerName yourservername
              RailsEnv production
              # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
              DocumentRoot /home/user/apps/projects/myapp/public
              <Directory /home/user/apps/projects/myapp/public>
                 # This relaxes Apache security settings.
                 AllowOverride all
                 # MultiViews must be turned off.
                 Options -MultiViews
              </Directory>
        </VirtualHost>
```

if you face any problem follow this link

```
http://nathanhoad.net/how-to-ruby-on-rails-ubuntu-apache-with-passenger
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I simply wasn't reading the instructions from the passenger error page. I just needed to disable a gem "simple-captcha", ran bundle install and everything went back to normal. Thanks